# Alternative definition of Lebesgue measurable set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider $\mathbb{R^d}$ with Lebesgue measure $\mu$.

Suppose that for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a Lebesgue measurable set $F$ such $\mu^* (E\Delta F) < \epsilon.$ Then $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.

I already know that converse is true.

The following is my try

for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is Lebesgue measurable set $F_n$ such that
$\mu^*(E \Delta F_n) < 2^{-n} \epsilon$.

Let $A$ be union of all $F_n$.

and $\mu^* (A-E)< \epsilon $ but it is false.

can you help me?